# Accessing Odoo localhost on LAN

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am testing Odoo v10 *(Formally known as OpenERP)* for my office. I have installed it on my server PC (windows 7 pro) having name "*NEBULA*" with IP *192.168.1.190* at port 80
Everything works fine when I accesses web address (http:// localhost/) or (http:// 127.0.0.1/) (http:// NEBULA/) or (http:// 192.168.1.190/) from my own PC browser where I have installed it.

But, When I tries from another PC connected to same LAN, browser is unable to reach http:// NEBULA/ or http:// 192.168.1.190/ .

I am getting PING reply on LAN pc from NEBULA for **PING NEBULA** and **PING 192.168.1.190** but, browser is unable to connect to same server.

Currently, I am not using any firewall on server.

Please help. How to reach **192.168.1.190** from browser over LAN ?

Comment: Are you sure the built-in firewall is disabled (I think there is one in w7) ? If this is the case, which error does the server returns (eg, 404, timeout, etc.) ? Also, you'll find more people able to help you here https://superuser.com/

Comment: Yes,  I have checked firewall. Its disabled. Browser says, unable to connect NEBULA. try again sometime.

Comment: I think, this somehow related with HOSTS file from system32 folder. Is it really?